# Checking whether a password contains only two capital letters using REGEX

Tags: regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to construct a regex to check whether only two CAPITAL letters are present in a password.

CODE1

```
import re
re.search(r'\A(?=.*[A-Z])','PassWords')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

CODE2

```
re.search(r'\A(?=.*[A-Z])','PassWorDs')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

Code2 contains 3 capital letters, but re matched that too. I don't want that. Where should I apply the quantifier

Comment: Why did you tag this `nsregularexpression`? Just adding random tags?

Comment: @melpomene it was a mistake.

Comment: `re.search(r'\A(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}[^A-Z]*\Z)','PassWorDs')`

Comment: Why do everything in a look-ahead?

Comment: Like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/qzdzou/1)?

Comment: @Gurman No, that regex matches at least 2 uppercase letters. See my suggestion above. That is what OP is looking for.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are correct, again. Thanks for pointing that out. :) [updated](https://regex101.com/r/qzdzou/2)